# Failed to assign function value to list

Tags: python

good evening,
I have a function in aws that returns a list, when I print it I display the values, but when I assign it to a variable I verify that it is blank. I have tried several things but I cannot find the error. please appreciate your help.

the lambda function correctly returns the value.
the value is:

os.system("echo value: '{}'".format( str(response['Payload'].read().decode('utf-8'))))

result is:
[{"bool_respuesta": 1, "resultado": "ganado", "error": "errores"}]

respuestaServicio= list( ( response['Payload'].read().decode('utf-8') )

os.system("echo Json respuesta archivo enviar_guia : '{}'".format( str(respuestaServicio)  ))

the result is an empty list: []

I don't know why the value is not assigned to the variable. when I don't put list (), I check that the type is a string. I don't know if it should return a list instead of a default string.

thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `response["Payload"]` is a stream – which can only be read once. You should save it to a variable on the first time you read it:

```
result = str(response['Payload'].read().decode('utf-8'))
os.system("echo value: '{}'".format(result)
respuestaServicio= list(result)
os.system("echo Json respuesta archivo enviar_guia : '{}'".format( str(respuestaServicio) ))
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it was assigning the value at the beginning and that solved the problem.